# How to setup tortoise svn repository on a windows server 2012 running iis for remote access

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, remote-access, windows-server-2012

I installed tortoise svn on a remote windows 2012 server which is running iis and created a repository using tortoise svn. but i can only access the repository locally using svn://localhost. when i try accessing it remotely with svn://directIP, i get the error "cannot connect to host 'directIP'... ". however the ip address is valid and i can hit it with a web browser. but iis is the server handling all incoming request on the remote windows 2012 server. am thinking windows server is not allowing unauthorized remote access to the server, that is why am unable to access the repository remotely...is there a way i can access my tortoise svn repository remotely while my iis is still running? please i need help!

Answer (score 2):

TortoiseSVN is an SVN Client and not a server. So you need a running SVN server like [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). 
Also read the TortoiseSVN manual about [accessing the repository](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup.html).

If you are really able to access the repository at `localhost` via the `svn://` protocol (and not with `file://` protocol) this would indicate that a subversion server is already running. In this case it might be a firewall problem and you have to open the svn port 3690 on your Windows server.

Comment: yes it does have subversion (svnserve) running on it, how do i open   up the port 3690. thanks

Comment: I have opened up port 3690 and have svnserve listening on it, however i still am unable to connect to the repo remotely

Comment: @victor Use [Zenmap](http://nmap.org/zenmap/) on your machine to check if the port on the server is really open for remote access.

Comment: but how then can i enable this port for remote access i have tried using the windows firewall with advance security wizard, am not sure if i configured it right

Answer (score 1):

Use VisualSVN Server for windows. I think they got a free one. You might wanna try it.